# Sql Server Project: Post deployment script(s)

Tags: sql-server, database-project

I have a database project and I'm wondering what best practice is for adding pre-determined data, like statuses, types, etc...

- Do I have 1 post deployment script for each status / type? OR
- Do I have 1 post deployment script that uses `:r someStatus.sql` for each status/type script?

I suppose a 3rd option could be to have all inserts in one giant script but that seems awful to me. In the past, I've used option 2, but I'm not sure why it was done this way.  Suggestions?

Comment: Out of interest, how much "pre-determined" data does your application have?

Comment: I'm not sure how one would quantify it, but there is statuses for orders, and accounts, etc... some or most of those also have types too.  Anything that is a status or type has these look up tables. So overall, its a small percentage to ACTUAL data of course, but I'd say about 10-12 tables get calculated for a production build.  But for test builds, I have a lot more that deploy test data.

Answer (score 0):

There's tools to package your data.
I have happily used RedGate SQL Packager (not free) and 
DBUnit XML datafiles extracted from development environment and sent to the database with an Ant `<dbunit>` task.

Answer (score 0):

For our scenario, we use a combination of #3 and #2. If we have a new build, we populate empty databases, set the post-deploy inserts that we normally use not to run, then populate the data after the entire build/publish. I tend to batch up related inserts as well so if I'm inserting 15 statuses, I add them in one script. The downside to that is that you need to make sure your script can be re-run and not cause issues so inserting into a temp table, then doing a left join against your actual table may be the best solution. It keeps the number of scripts down to a more manageable size.

For incremental releases, I tend to batch inserts by Story (using Scrum) so related scripts go together. It also helps me know when a script has been run in production and can be safely removed from the project.

You may also want to look at having a "reference" database of some sort where you only store the reference values, then perhaps a tool such as Red-Gate's Data Compare to pull over the appropriate set of data. The Pro version can be automated/scripted so you may have an easier way to pull in new data for testing. This may be your best solution in the long run as you can easily set up which tables you want to copy and set filters on data.